# three.js: can't find variable THREE & unexpected string litera l'./polyfills.js'

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

[erroe screen shot[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAM2S.png)

Absolutely a beginner in three.js
not sure what causes the two errors.
Errors:
1. Can't find variable: THREE line 21:31 frame.html
2. import './polyfills.js'; line 1 three.js

```js
import './polyfills.js'; error:import './polyfills.js'; line 1 three.js

   ----- //a bunch of other imports
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   //other
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();  error:Can't find variable: THREE
        
//OTHER
```

Comment: Have you not the bundled version/minified? Why not just get it from a CDN?

Comment: Use this: https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js

Comment: @ChrisG thanks! but where should i use that? do i import it directly using the link or should i create a new js file and copy that?

Comment: @JulianaXie That's up to you, both methods should work fine. Just make sure you put it as `src` in a `<script>`. You can also right-click the link and "Save Link as..." to your project folder.

Comment: @ChrisG I added the link directly but browser reports the same two errors.

Comment: @ChrisG Here's the code I added:<script>
        src = "https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"
    </script>

Comment: @JulianaXie You need `<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>` (`src` is an attribute and goes inside the opening tag, and you also need the full URL)

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded three.js, you have to use the following path **three.js-master/build/three.js** or **three.js-master/build/three.min.js**

It is possible that you are confusing it with **three.js-master/src/Three.js**.